# Not able to locate iframe using cypress

Tags: testing, iframe, cypress, integration-testing, e2e-testing

I am using cypress v5.4 to test braintree paypal dropin with test visa card but unable to locate into iframe. Since cypress doesn't provide a native way to deal with iframes hence I am creating a custom command, basically to traverse through an iframe. But it doesn't work.

here is how `command.js` looks like.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframeBody', () => {
  return cy
   .get('#braintree-hosted-field-number')
   .its('0.contentDocument.body')
   .should('not.be.empty')
   .then(cy.wrap)
  });
```

And here is my test `paymentMethods.js`

```
cy.get(".braintree-option.braintree-option__card")
  .should("be.visible")
  .click()
cy.get("div.ModalContent__BottomSection-b9lci0-1", {timeout:5000})
cy.getIframeBody()
  .find('#credit-card-number').type('4111111111111111');
```

It stuck when wrapping iframe into cypress

[image: stuck here]

HTML:

[image]

All help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is this `div.ModalContent__BottomSection-b9lci0-1`? It isn't in the HTML sample you provided and your failure is before you try to use your getIframeBody custom command?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use the [cypress iframe](https://gitlab.com/kgroat/cypress-iframe) plugin.

1. To install use the command `npm install -D cypress-iframe`.
2. In your `cypress/support/commands.js` file, add the following:

```js
import 'cypress-iframe'
// or
require('cypress-iframe')
```

3. Then in your test write:

```js
cy.iframe('#braintree-hosted-field-number')
  .find('#credit-card-number')
  .type('4111111111111111')
```

Comment: Let me try to install. Thank you. Is version matters when I work with iframe @AlapanDas?

Comment: For this plugin, cypress < > 10 should work.

Comment: this plug in not a good option, it just collapsed my project.

Comment: This worked for me; perfectly if i may say so myself. Such a neat solution; thank you to who ever built the NPM module. Had such trouble looking for a solution to this.